# What is a natural number?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, integers

According to page 25 of the book *A First Course in Real Analysis*, an inductive set is a set of real numbers such that $0$ is in the set and for every real number $x$ in the set, $x + 1$ is also in the set and a natural number is a real number that every inductive set contains. The problem with that definition is that it is circular because the real numbers are constructed from the natural numbers.

Comment: (1) The author of the book would be helpful.  (2) The real numbers can be defined axiomatically, without relying on a construction from the naturals.  Specifically, the real numbers are the unique (up to isomorphism) complete ordered field.  If you define the reals axiomatically, the argument is not circular.

Comment: You can start with an axiomatized real numbers as a "complete ordered field," then define the natural numbers inside there. Probably useful as a way to avoid all the messy construction of $\mathbb R$ in a real analysis class.

Comment: Is that actually given as a definition? Could the author just be saying that it is a property of $ \mathbb R $ – while possibly waving his hands about the identification of a subset of $ \mathbb R $ with $ \mathbb N $ and the question of what those number systems “are”?

Comment: Sounds as if the authors are  Murray H. Protter and Charles B. Morrey Jr. and the book is ISBN: 978-1-4612-6460-6 (Print) 978-1-4419-8744-0 (Online); taken from https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-8744-0 – you might edit that in.

Comment: _“What is a natural number?”_ A component of a mathematical model formalising the concept of counting **or** something we believe is so modelled. We can make multiple such models, they just need to behave right. And a better question may be _“What does a natural number do?”_ (Memo to self: read _Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen?_)

Comment: @PJTraill  Thanks for the reference.  I can't access more than the first two pages of the text, but if that is the right book, they start with the field axioms, which makes me confident that my answer is the one provided by the authors.

Comment: I think the question title needs clarifying. The question has generated answers along two very different lines, one line answering "what is a natural number?" and the other answering "does this definition in the book work?"

Comment: **If** the book is Protter & Morrey, I agree that the exposition is quite weird: 1. assumed existence of the *reals* (axiom for fields + axiom of inequality); 2. defined an *integer* as a real that is either zero, a natural or the negative of a natural; 3. defined the *naturals*.

Comment: Compare with e.g. Ethan Bloch, [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PR7).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews While that is sort of true, you will probably have trouble with existence. Showing a complete ordered field is unique up to isomorphism isn't hard but showing it exists is likely to need a construction (I wonder if you could get away with some smart model/proof theoretic argument though.)

Comment: The point is that there is only one possible inductive subset of the reals ... and if it exists it must be isomorphic to the naturals by any reasonable definition of the naturals. When the reals are constructed from the naturals, they are generally a different kind of thing from the naturals, so the isomorphism is an important technicality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose we did start with some notion of "natural number" which we used to construct a model of the real numbers.

Then even in this setting, the quoted definition is *still* not circular, because it's defining a *new* notion of "natural number" that will henceforth be used instead of the previous notion of "natural number".

We could give the new notion a different name, but there isn't really any point; the new version of "natural numbers" has an obvious isomorphism with the old version so it's not really any different from the old one in any essential way.

---

There are a number of reasons why an exposition of real analysis might construct the natural numbers from the real numbers; the two most prominent are:

- It is technically convenient to have the natural numbers be a subset of the real numbers
- It makes the exposition somewhat more agnostic about foundations; it simply needs the real numbers as a starting point

Answer (score 21):

We can define the real numbers axiomatically to be the unique (up to isomorphism) complete ordered field.  In this setting, $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, \le)$ must satisfy the properties

1. $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ is a field (i.e. both of the operations are commutative and associative, multiplication distributes over addition, every element has an additive inverse, and every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse).
2. $(\mathbb{R},\le)$ is a totally ordered set (i.e. the relation $\le$ is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric, and for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\ne b$, then exactly one of $a\le b$ or $b\le a$ holds).
3. The order is compatible with the field structure in the sense that $a \le b$ implies that $a+c \le b+c$ for all $c$, and if $0 \le a,b$, then $0 \le a\cdot b$.  (We could actually deduce the properties of an order from these properties plus the comparability axiom above, but I personally find it easier to attack it this way.)
4. $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,\le)$ is complete, in the sense that if a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an upper bound, then it has a *least* upper bound.
5. In this context, we probably have to take the existence of the real numbers as an axiom (i.e. the existence of at least one totally ordered field), as well (thank you for pointing that out, DRF).  Alternatively, see the addendum.

It is a bit of work to show that if $(X,+',\cdot',\le')$ satisfies these axioms, then $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but it can be done.  In any case, we can (and often do) define the real numbers axiomatically in this manner.

Note that there is nothing in the above about natural numbers, rational numbers, Dedekind cuts, or Cauchy completeness.  The real numbers are given to you on a silver platter.  From this, it is then possible to define the naturals in (more or less) the manner described in the question.

---

Addendum:  Alternatively, instead of declaring the existence of the reals by fiat (item 5, above), we could build them up from scratch via the usual process (i.e. build the integers as equivalence classes of naturals, then the rationals as equivalence classes of integers, then the reals as Dedekind cuts).  This construction of the reals will satisfy the above axioms.

From this construction, define an inductive set $S$ to be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (where an element of $\mathbb{R}$ is a Dedekind cut, which is...) with the properties that

1. $0 \in S$, and
2. if $x\in S$, then $x+1\in S$.

Then define $N$ to be the intersection of all inductive sets, i.e.
$$ N = \bigcap_{\text{$S$ an inductive set}} S. $$
This set $N$ is a subset of the real numbers, and behaves (in every meaningful way) as the natural numbers—$N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.  So perhaps it is reasonable to call $N$ the set of real-natural numbers.  But I don't like having two sets of numbers running around called "natural numbers", so I am going to be lazy, and drop the "real-" part, and just say that $N$ is the set of natural numbers.  I'll probably also go ahead and typeset it as $\mathbb{N}$, and write things like $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

---

That being said, this "inductive set" definition of the natural numbers comes from a book on analysis, not axiomatic set theory.  The goal of the book is to do *real analysis* (i.e. to study limits, differentiation, integration, etc. in the context of real functions of real nubmers).  If you had to start from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and build up your number systems from there, you could never get to the actual results of analysis in a reasonable page count.  You have to build a foundation *somewhere*.  As such, starting from the assumption that the reals exist reasonable, and extracting the natural numbers from the reals is fine.

Comment: Until we know definitely how the book defines $ \mathbb N $ & $ \mathbb R $ we do not know if that resolves the problem stated in the “question”.

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the above about natural numbers, but the *completeness* axiom requires subsets. So you are working in a set theory, most likely. If ZFC, then the natural numbers already exist as an axiom.

Comment: Why not just use the peano axioms?

Comment: I like your phrase "given on a silver platter". +1 for the same. For the very same reason I don't like the axiomatic approach to reals. The approach trivializes the completeness property of reals whereas in reality that is the only non-trivial property which reals possess. Something like "completeness" has to be hard earned rather than received on a silver platter.

Comment: How do you get that what you defined actually exists? Uniqueness isn't hard but existence seems to require a construction.

Comment: @6005 My understanding was that the goal was to build the natural numbers from the reals without starting the construction from the natural numbers.  Call the set from ZFC (my recollection is that ZFC only gives us *an* infinite set, this needed be *the natural numbers*) something else, then obtain the natural numbers in this way.  Or build the real axiomatically as above, and show that the usual natural numbers agree.

Comment: @PyRulez Because the original poster wanted to understand how building the naturals out of the reals could be non-circular.  As I understand it, the goal isn't to build the reals, but to build the naturals from the reals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The definition comes from a real analysis text book.  In that context, completeness is vital, but building up completeness from scratch isn't nearly so important.  If the goal is to get to limits and derivatives as quickly as possible, this is an entirely reasonable approach.

Comment: The concepts of calculus (limits, continuity, derivative, integral) can be defined without any appeal to completeness. The completes is not needed to set these things up but to establish that these concepts lead to an interesting and beautiful theory as all the vital existential theorems are dependent on completeness. In a sense completeness is what separates analysis from algebra. Most presentations of completeness are rather boring and I believe that is the reason why newer textbooks started taking it as an axiom.

Comment: I thought the Archimedean property was also required to make $\mathbb{R}$ unique - that the subset $\mathbb{N}$ as defined in the question has no upper bound.  Otherwise, an instance of the "nonstandard reals" would satisfy all the axioms.

Comment: @DanielSchepler $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean, but that follows from the other axioms.  Specifically, completeness axiom.

Comment: I fixed the answer to talk about building natural numbers from the real numbers.

Comment: I guess the original natural numbers you start with could be the finite von Neumann ordinals but those aren't the sets people call natural numbers. Some people probably also work in an extension of ZF where they assume that real numbers are urelements that aren't in the von Neumann universe.

Comment: @Timothy Again, the point is that the real numbers can be defined axiomatically without first requiring that the natural numbers be defined.  If you have a set with the properties of the real numbers, we can extract from that set "the" natural numbers via the definition given.  There are many isomorphic constructions of the reals; from the perspective of the definition given by Protter and Morrey, it doesn't really matter which you start with (though they seem to start with the axiomatization I gave, above).

Comment: Is that because the people who made the curriculum decided they know it's already been proven in ZF that a complete ordered field exists so it's good enough teaching students that the set of all real numbers satisfies certain properties because it's true and they don't need to teach the proof? If a specific job is seeking people really good at math and a course is designed to test that, they could teach how to write a formal proof in ZF and ask on a test question to write a formal proof that there is a complete ordered field that is unique up to isomorphism or to make it harder in NF.

Comment: @Timothy As I alluded to in the last paragraph, you have to start somewhere.  If you are taking a course in analysis (which is the topic of the book *A First Course in Real Analysis*), then you are going to be studying real numbers.  You need a basic working definition of the reals; you *could* start with a more basic construction, but this takes time.  Since the course is on *analysis* and not basic set theory of foundations, the time it takes to build the reals is wasted.  It is better to assert the existence of the reals (via some axiomatization), and work from there.

Comment: Obviously, as a student studies more mathematics, they may be interested in the kinds of issues that you raise, at which point it is reasonable to start talking about set theory or logic.  But these are topics for other courses.

Answer (score 5):

You have to start *some*where.

And in mathematics, you have to start from *some* axioms.

If you choose to start from the axioms for the real numbers, then using them you define the natural numbers exactly as you quoted, and using that that definition you can *prove* that the Peano axioms are true.

If instead you choose to start from the Peano axioms for the natural numbers, then using them you can define the real numbers, and using that definition you can *prove* that the axioms for the real numbers are true.

Either one of those provides an answer to your question. You may not like that answer, but that's how things go. What you cannot do is to avoid choosing your axioms.

Nonetheless, perhaps there is still a way to break this vicious loop?

Well, actually, there is, by making a different choice of axioms. You can, instead, choose the basic axioms for set theory, also known as the Zermelo-Frankel axioms or ZF for short.

If you choose to start from the ZF axioms, then using them you can define the natural numbers using the [Von Neumann definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory). Using that definition, you can then *prove* that the Peano axioms are true. And then, as already said, you can use the Peano axioms (which in this scheme are now theorems instead of axioms) to define the real numbers and use that definition to prove that the axioms for the real numbers are true.

Comment: +1 for recommending Von Neumann. But do you have an issue with the C of ZFC?

Comment: Well, the construction of the natural numbers works in ZF, that's all. I'm happy to call it a ZFC theorem, just like I would be happy to refer to a theorem about all groups as a theorem about abelian groups, but it gives more information as I stated it.

Answer (score 3):

*Defining* the natural numbers (to within isomorphism) as a distinguished subset of a complete ordered field (COF) seems mathematically slick, but is unsatisfactory in two ways. First, definition should go from the simple to the complex and from the elementary to the advanced—not the other way round. Second, in order for the definition of a COF, and hence of the distinguished subset, to make sense, it must be proved that (A) any two COFs are isomorphic and (B) a COF exists. Let us grant A (which is not exactly trivial) and look at B. The simplest way to establish B is to construct $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$ via Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$. But then what is $\Bbb Q$? The simplest way to define it is in terms of equivalence classes of pairs of elements of $\Bbb Z$. And $\Bbb Z$? Why, it is just a set of equivalence classes of pairs of elements of $\Bbb N$. Thus we have come full circle.

Now, it is true that all this set-theoretic structure is unwanted baggage when our aim is to get on and do real analysis, in which we would like to have simply $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$ (the last one for good measure). But this is not really a problem. Having established existence from the bottom up, we can identify an isomorphic copy of each more basic structure within each more encompassing one, and agree henceforth to use these copies (in $\Bbb C$, say) rather than the originals, for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Because of some of the comments, I thought of more to add.

We can define the set of all natural numbers to satisfy the axioms of Peano arithmetic and then from that, we can construct the rational numbers and then the real numbers from the Dedekind cuts of rational numbers. After the set of all real numbers has been defined in this way, it can be proven that this definition of the set of all natural numbers describes the same set as the other definition of the set of all natural numbers. Defining the set of all real numbers as a totally ordered field then defining the natural numbers from it is unsatisfactory because it doesn't prove that a totally ordered field exists. In Zermelo-Frankel set theory, it can probably be proven that constructing the set of all real numbers in the other way gives rise to a totally ordered field and that every totally ordered field is isomorphic to that one.

Comment: If you want to prove the existence of a totally ordered field, you can go through the usual song and dance of defining the natural numbers axiomatically, then building up to the reals via Dedekind cuts or Cauchy completeness.  Abstract nonsense tells us that there is at most one (up to isomorphism) totally ordered field, and we have a way of getting such a thing.  With that in hand, define the *real* natural numbers as above, then show that the two definitions are isomorphic (as semigroups?).  It still isn't circular.